# Base R: odd behavior with filter and equals operator

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble **pan** with a numeric column called **var**.

```
> class(pan$variable)
[1] "numeric"
```

It has a set of values of 0.8 to 0.9:

```
> unique(pan$variable)
[1] 0.800 0.825 0.850 0.875 0.900
```

However, when I try to filter **pan** on a specific value of **var**, it only works for certain values!

**Expected behavior:**

```
> filter(pan,variable == 0.8)
# A tibble: 510 x 20
```

**Abnormal behavior:**

```
> filter(pan,variable == 0.825)
# A tibble: 0 x 20
```

In fact, in this scenario, I only get results for 0.8, 0.875, and 0.9!  Filter brings up nothing for 0.825 and 0.85.

```
> filter(pan,variable == 0.85)
# A tibble: 0 x 20
```

I've tried restarting my RStudio session, but no change in behavior.  I've built my own "filter" function and the abnormal behavior continues:

```
sum <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(pan)) {
  if (pan$variable[i] == 0.8) {
     sum <- sum + 1
  }
}
print(sum)
```

When I run this little filter function for values of 0.8, 0.875, and 0.9 it returns a value of ~510, as expected, but it returns 0 for values of 0.825 and 0.85.

```
> pan$variable[511]
[1] 0.825
> pan$variable[511]==0.825
[1] FALSE
```

Has anyone every encountered such odd behavior in R?  What am I missing, since I've confirmed the class of **var** is numeric, but won't test TRUE for certain values?

Comment: Thanks Gregor - I've heard about that but haven't actually run into that problem until now....

Comment: Don't use `==` with floats. The simplest work around is to hard-code a tolerance, something like `filter(pan, abs(variable - 0.8) < 1e-10)`. A nice built-in value for the tolerance is `.Machine$double.eps`

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to use `==` to test for equality of floating-point values, because of [how they are stored in memory](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html). You are better off checking for two values being within `epsilon` of each other.